# What architecture of neural network is good for this kind of data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

[image: This is where data comes from and what is the expected output]

In my test dataset, radius of A is around 0.5 and range of X,Y is around [0..10], and A is located at x=9 y=3

I generated 50K samples, of those 10% positive, and cannot find approach where NN does not overfit and produces something sensible on validation dataset. I tried dense architecture only.

I understand that inputs multiplication (required for solving the equations on picture) is not part of standard dense layers, but can be achieved with deep enough architecture. Does is worth it? Or should i write my own layers (vector multiplication)? What about division?

Is it a good task for NN? Maybe there's a better coding of input data?
If not, what is suitable approach in data mining / machine learning area?

Ideally, this is task about detecting hidden variable dependencies in input data, they may easily be non-linear (e.g. 3 points define spline, let's assume 2 is maximum power) and noisy (e.g. there are maybe 20 points, such that Yi=1.0 when only some 4 points form crossing line (same 4 points across all dataset, e.g. 1st, 3rd, 9th and 10th)). Where do I look? I'm asking too much?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you simply evaluate it with neural networks?

Comment: tried dense layers (8 layers max) with various intermediate sizes up to hundred neurons.

Comment: And what were the results?

Comment: > cannot find approach where NN does not overfit and produces something sensible on validation dataset (if it does not overfit, it does not converge, validation dataset too)

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simple task for NN. I think the key problem here is about preventing overfitting. It is encouraged that overfits the task first and then solves oveffiting problem.

#### Handling Overfitting

1. less layers, less units of each layer
2. regularlization such as dropout regularlization, L2 regularlization
3. data augmentation (basically more training data)
4. early stopping (add a better stopping criteria)
5. ...